# 'GET' Method Reading from MongoDB, TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

**Documents:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5532211a6d88889eb26f6556"), "id" : 0, "name" : "Latte", "quantity" : "1", "milk" : "Skim", "size" : "grande" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("553221c56d88889eb26f6557"), "id" : 1, "name" : "Americano", "quantity" : 3, "milk" : "No", "size" : "short" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("553221e36d88889eb26f6558"), "id" : 2, "name" : "Americano", "quantity" : 1, "milk" : null, "size" : "short" }
```

**Code:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps

connection = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = connection.RESTbucks
collection  = db.order


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/order/<int:order_ID>', methods=['GET'])
def get_order(order_ID):
    orders = collection.find()
    json_orders = dumps(orders)
    target_order_ID = [target_order_ID for target_order_ID in json_orders if target_order_ID["id"] == order_ID]
    if target_order_ID == order_ID:
        return jsonify({'order': json_orders[order_ID]})
    else:
        return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)
```

When I access "http://localhost:5000/order/1", I expect result

```
"{ "_id" : ObjectId("553221c56d88889eb26f6557"), "id" : 1, "name" : "Americano", "quantity" : 3, "milk" : "No", "size" : "short" }"
```

But occur `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`
What should I do for expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to fix these two lines:

```
json_orders = dumps(orders)
target_order_ID = [target_order_ID for target_order_ID in json_orders if target_order_ID["id"] == order_ID]
```

First `dumps` makes a string, so `json_orders` is a string. When you iterate through it in the list comprehension, you are iterating through the characters of a string, which are themselves one-character strings. Then you try to index these strings with `["id"]` which is the source of your error.

Note also that your second line has another error. You are assigning to `target_ID` a list, when it appears you just want one element from the list. You've IMHO overused the name `target_order_ID`, so a little cleanup might be helpful there too.